# Write to protected registry key

Tags: registry, nsis, access-control

I am trying to write to a protected registry key on Windows 7/8:

```
Section "WriteToRegistry"
    # Give all authentificated users (BUILTIN\Users) full access on
    # the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Vendor\SomeApp
    AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey \
        HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" "(BU)" "FullAccess"

    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" "ATExe" "mystring"
SectionEnd
```

I also tried:

```
Section "WriteToRegistry"

    AccessControl::GetCurrentUserName "" "$0"

    Pop $0

    MessageBox MB_OK $0 ;mzelensky

    AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner \
        HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" "ATExe" $0

    AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey \
        HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" "ATExe" "FullAccess"

    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" "ATExe" "mystring"

SectionEnd
```

And it does nothing. What is wrong?

**Update** This listing pops OK messages, but does not do anything actually:

```
Section "ProtectedRegistryKey"

    AccessControl::GetCurrentUserName

    Pop $0
    MessageBox MB_OK $0 ;Michael Zelensky

    AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner \
        HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" $0

    Pop $2
    MessageBox MB_OK $2 ;ok

    AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey \
        HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" \
        "$0" "FullAccess"

    Pop $3
    MessageBox MB_OK $3 ;ok

    WriteRegStr \
        HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" \
        "ATExe1" "osk_1.exe"

    Pop $4
    MessageBox MB_OK $4 ;empty message

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include the value name "ATExe" in those parameters, registry permissions only apply to keys, not values.

```
AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk"  $0

AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk" $0 "FullAccess"
```

You also need to pop the return value from those calls...

I would also recommend that you try to restore the ownership to something sensible:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner HKCU "Software\Test" "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
Pop $0 
${If} $0 != "ok"
    Pop $0 ; Throw away error details
    AccessControl::SetRegKeyOwner HKCU "Software\Test" "(S-1-5-18)" ;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    Pop $0
    ${IfThen} $0 != "ok" ${|} Pop $0 ${|} ; Throw away error details
${EndIf}
```

Comment: It just doesn't work...
Return values are OK, but the registry doesn't update.

Comment: Which NSIS version and which plugin version? Try getting the latest plugin version from the wiki (Updated today). Please edit your question with the new code that fails with "ok".

Comment: NSIS 3.0b0
AccessControl v1.0.8.0

Comment: Try v1.0.8.1, should fix the bogus "ok" return value.

Comment: Thank you, Anders! 1.0.8.1 didn't help - all the same. I updated the question body with my code listing.

Comment: It works for me. Remember that on a 64 bit system you have to use SetRegView 64 if you want to change the "64 bit registry".

Comment: Wow! At least it worked with SetRegView64! Thousand of thanks, Anders! You are making a great product!

Comment: It works without SetRegView also, it just sets the other key, look under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node :)